# Build GRPC c++ for android using NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to cross compile grpc c++(version 1.19) for Android from Mac using NDK.

I have tried below way to compile it for Andoid architecture arm64.

```
$ export GRPC_CROSS_COMPILE=true
$ export PATH=/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:$PATH
$ export SYSROOT=/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/sysroot
$ export HOST_CC="/usr/bin/clang"
$ export HOST_CXX="/usr/bin/clang++"
$ export HOST_LD="/usr/bin/ld"
$ export CC=“/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android28-clang --sysroot $SYSROOT"
$ export CXX=“/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android28-clang++ —sysroot $SYSROOT"
$ export LD=“/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld”
$ export LDXX=“/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android28-clang++"
$ export AR=“/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar"
$ export STRIP=“/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-strip"
$ export PROTOBUF_CONFIG_OPTS="--host=aarch64-linux-android-4.9 --with-sysroot=${SYSROOT} —with-protoc=/usr/local/bin/protoc CFLAGS=‘-march=arm64-v8a -D__ANDROID_API__=28' CXXFLAGS='-frtti -fexceptions -march=arm64-v8a -D__ANDROID_API__=28' LIBS='-llog -lz -lc++_static’"
$ export HAS_PKG_CONFIG=false
$ export GRPC_CROSS_LDOPTS="-L$SYSROOT -L/usr/local/cross/lib”
$ export GRPC_CROSS_AROPTS="cr —-target=elf32-little”
$ make
```

it is throwing this error

```
[MAKE] Generating cache.mk
[LD] Linking /Users/laxmi/grpc/libs/opt/libaddress_sorting.dylib
make: “/Users/laxmi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld”: No such file or directory
make: *** [/Users/laxmi/grpc/libs/opt/libaddress_sorting.dylib] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like that file is missing for you. Is there any file in that directory ending on `ld`?

Comment: yes it is available.

Comment: `make` seems to disagree. Can you `ls -l` the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your lines have curly quotes in them (`“` and `”`) instead of straight quotes (`"`). This is something to watch out for when you're copy-pasting code from non-code sources (article or PDF). Replace all curly quotes with straight quotes and try again.